# Topology: What is a quick way to check whether a subset $D$ is dense in $(X, \mathcal{T})$?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition, problem-solving

Def $1$: Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, then $D \subseteq X$ is dense if $\overline {D} = X$

Def $2$:  $x \in \overline D$ iff  for all $U \in \mathcal{T}, x \in U \implies D \cap U \neq \varnothing$

I find myself not being able to connect definition of dense and definition of closure. Thus I don't have a quick way to check whether a set is dense or not.

What is a good procedure for checking whether a set is dense in $X$?

I was thinking that if all $x \in D$ is contained in some open set, then the set is dense, but I do not know to use the definition to prove that is true.

Comment: Another definition which is a combination of your def. 1 and def. 2 is: if $D$ is dense, given any point $x\in X$, any open subset containing $x$, i.e. $x\in U$ open, meets $D$ , $D\cap U\neq \emptyset$. Verbally any open neighborhood of any point touches $D$ inevitably.

Comment: @Hamed But isn't that just the definition of the closure? $\overline {D}$ is the closure of $D$ if for any point $x \in X, x \in U, U \in \mathcal{T}, D \cap U \neq \varnothing$?

Comment: You can leave out "points". $D$ is dense iff its intersection with every non-empty open set is not empty. Equivalently: $D$ is dense iff every non-empty open set will contain elements of $D$.

Comment: @drhab Sorry but I still can't see why "$D$ is dense iff every non-empty open set will contain elements of $D$" is different from "$\overline D$ is the closure of $D$ iff every non-empty open set will contain elements of $D$". Because in the definition, we can write $\overline {D} = \{x \in X| \forall U \in \mathcal{T}, x \in U \implies D \cap U \neq \varnothing\}$, but $\overline{D}$ is not necessarily $X$. Could you elaborate on your comment in answer format? Thank ou

Comment: There is no essential difference between the statements $\overline{D}=X$ and "every non-empty open set contains elements of $D$". Do you see that, or do you want me to explain that in an answer?

Comment: @drhab can you elaborate when $\overline D \subset X$ and when $\overline D = X$. I think that will really high light the difference. Thank you

Comment: If $U$ is open and non-empty and $U$ contains no elements of $D$ then $D\subseteq U^c$ where $U^c$ is closed. Consequently $\overline{D}\subseteq U^c$. Then $\varnothing\neq U\subseteq X-\overline{D}$ so $\overline{D}$ is a **proper** subset of $X$ hence is not dense. So if $\overline{D}=X$ such $U$ will not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A characterization for a dense set is:

(*) A set $D\subseteq X$ is dense if every non-empty open set $U$ will contain elements of $D$.

If this is the case then it cannot happen that $\overline{D}$ is a proper subset of $X$. This because in that case $U:=X-\overline{D}$ is open, non-empty and contains no elements of $D$. So we conclude that $\overline{D}=X$.

If conversely $\overline{D}=X$ and $U$ is an open set with $x\in U$ then $x\in\overline{D}$ implies that $U\cap D\neq\varnothing$ (as stated in "Def 2" in your answer).

Proved is now that (*) agrees with "Def 1" in your answer.

Comment: 1. I think that should be iff (?) 2. so we can write $\overline D = X$ iff $\forall U \in \mathcal{T}, U \cap D \neq \varnothing$. So the difference is that the requirement $x \in U$ drops out. $x \in U$ drops out because $\overline D = X, U \subset X$, so $x \in U \implies x \in X = \overline D$, is this the correct way of thinking about this? So a quick way to check is to intersect some $U \in \mathcal{T}$ with $D$, if any happens to be empty then $D$ is not dense, otherwise $D$ is dense

Comment: 1) In a *definition/characterization* (almost) always the word "if" is used. But it is okay then to interpret this "if" as "if and only if". Yes, just check wether open non-empty sets exist that have an empty intersection with $D$. If that is not the case then $D$ is dense. Example $\mathbb Q\subseteq\mathbb R$. Note that every open interval $(a,b)$ contains elements of $\mathbb Q$. So $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.